# Xcode - How to make it use different plist file for same code base, different targets

Tags: xcode, plist, xcode-build-settings

I have a code base that I need to build out to two different targets.  The only difference is they read different config.plists, config-1.plist for target #1 and config-2.plist for target #2.  What do I need to do in the building to achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this:

- Select your project from the navigator to the left
- Select the target you want to change (under TARGETS)
- Click "Build Settings"
- Search for "Info.plist"

In the Packaging section, you should see a setting called *Info.plist file*.

- Change that to you "config-2.plist" or whatever you want.

You also need to create the two plist-files of course.

Comment: and don't set targets for Info-..,plist  ! leave them empty

Comment: @djdance only if we dont need them